# Can't upload sketches to breadboard Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, uploading

- I have an ATmega328 chip with the boot-loader installed.
- I also have an Arduino Uno with the ATmega328 chip removed.
- I hooked this chip up to a breadboard with the proper 22pF caps, 16MHz crystal, and 10kΩ pull-up resistor.
- The LED flasher was loaded prior, and this works fine when I hook an LED and resistor up to pin 19. I have confirmed my external crystal works by disconnecting it, and the flashing stops, when I reconnect the crystal, the flashing continues.
- Power is fed from my Arduino Uno 5 V out to the DIY Arduino
- I connected the reset wire, and data wires, ensuring pin 2 went to RX and pin 3 to TX.

**In the software**

First to confirm everything works, I removed the chip from the breadboard and placed it in the Arduino. The sketch uploaded successfully using the settings:  Arduino Uno as board and AVRISP mkll as programmer.

Now I move the chip to the breadboard, and ensure all the wires are connected. The LED starts to blink again, but when I try to upload the sketch, I get an error:

`avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding`

I ensure continuity between the reset, TX, RX, and power connections and try different settings like Arduino as ISP and different boards under settings including the Duemilanove and nano but nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

[image: Photo of circuit on breadboard]

Comment: So you have 5 wires, right? 5V, Gnd, Tx, Rx and Reset? Stick to the Uno in the boards menu, after all it worked as a Uno when plugged in, didn't it? Can you post a photo please?

Comment: 5 wires, works when chip is plugged into the socket.

Comment: Never mind, found the problem. My software switched to the bluetooth for some reason after I changed some other settings. Hate when the simple things always get me

Answer (score 2):

Answered by Skyler440:

> Never mind, found the problem. My software switched to the bluetooth for some reason after I changed some other settings.

*Converted to answer to reduce unanswered questions.*

Comment: @ChetanBhargava : Removed request. However is their a link for that assertion?

Comment: well, on raspberry pi SE, I did same thing and I was told my a mod not to do that. That was a while back on a chat session.

Comment: [Found it here](http://i.imgur.com/rP4HWEo.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two AVR ICs present on the Arduino board, one is used for the USB to ICSP interface and the other one is the μC which you're using.

As I've noticed that you've tried to connect `Tx` and `Rx` pins including reset for programming the IC. Those pins are used for communication on serial protocol, where as the AVR in Arduino is programmed using SPI Protocol, so you should be using MISO, MOSI, SCK, SS (they're pins 13-10 respectively) and Reset pins on the Arduino, then the AVR which is used as USB-SPI bridge for programming can communicate with the μC and program it.